# Alternative solution to sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets, synchronization, client-server, thread-sleep

I made an application in java between two machines where each one at the time makes some computation over some data and send to the other  to do its part. I managed to do it using sockets. Therefore, both machines play server and client depending on which part of the code they are running. However, it demands a lot of synchronization so that will have already the data to compute and so far I managed to do it with a `Thread.sleep();` but since I put a big margin for the sleep time, it results on a lot of idle time.
I was wondering if there is any alternative to this so that I have automatic synchronization.

Comment: Have you considered using RMI?

Comment: What would be the advantage of using it?

Comment: The main advantage of RMI over sockets is ease of use. You design your system using the OO paradigm. Synchronization is fairly simple, as you can just use Java's built in monitors.  In any case using Thread.sleep as a synchronization tool is not a good idea; it is not provably safe.  If you could add a bit more detail about your application, I might be able to explain better. If you simply need the two machines to take turns operating on the data then make one the client and the other the server. The client does its part, calls the server, the server does its part and returns, and so on.

Comment: Thread.sleep() is wrong approach to synchronization. Just read socket in blocking mode until enough data has been read, then process them or pass to another thread to process.

Answer (score 2):

There is a java framework called apache MINA which abstracts the complexity and limit of pure sockets. You can find more details here: http://mina.apache.org/